# Insert element after every element in list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to write a predicate that will insert a given element after every element in a list and will print resulting list. I want to use recurrsion for this.

For example: my list is `[1,2,3,4,5]` and I want to insert `0` after every element. So the resulting list should be: `[1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0]`.

I wrote this:

```
add([],X).
add([H|T],[H|[X|T1]]):-
    add(T,T1).
add([H|T],[H|T1]):-
    add(T,T1).
```

And I run this like: `add([1,2,3], 0).` but Prolog says only `No`. What does it mean? How can I improve this? Thanks

Edit:

It works, but shows some warnings about singleton variables:

```
add([], X, []).  
add([H|T], X, [H|[X|T1]]):- add(T, X, T1).  
add([H|T], X, [H|T1]):- add(T, X, T1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog definitions do not "return" values, like in other languages. Instead, you should state facts about the relationship like so:

```
add(List1, InsertedElement, List2) :- ...
```

So, the first fact would be

```
add([], _, []).
```

I'll leave the rest as a homework exercise.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this: h`add([], _, []).

add([H|T],[H|[_|T1]]):- add(T,T1).

add([H|T],[H|T1]):- add(T,T1).`. I run questions like `add([1,2,3], 99, X).` but the result is False, instead of a new list in `X`.

Comment: @mazix Your definitions have 2 arguments. They should have 3.

Comment: @mazix Replace the first statement with what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add( []     , _ , []       ) .      
add( [X|Xs] , V , [X,V|Ys] ) :- add(Xs,V,Ys).
```

And if you execute

```
add( [1,2,3], 0, L ).
```

You should get

```
L = [1,0,2,0,3,0]
true
```